# SSIS Getting Execute Sql Task result set object

Tags: c#, ssis

I have an execute sql task item and it is getting multiple rows of data from a stored proc.

Declared a variable `ObjShipment` under the variable table and assigned it under the Result set with the following info:

```
Result Set:    Full result set
Result Name:   0
Variable Name: User::ObjShipment
```

I have written a script task with the ObjShipment variable assigned to ReadOnly an am wondering how to retrieve the data within it?

The stored proc returns multiple rows like `Id, ItemId, DateCreated..`, but how do I retrieve them say if I am only interested in the ItemId?  And since it returns multiple rows there could be more than one ItemId.

I am new with ssis any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I answered your question, but all of that being said, depending on your overall package's goal, unless you need to iterate through each of those itemIDs and act on them independently, this sort of query->object Execute SQL task is often times not the most efficient way to do things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So generally speaking you use Object variables within an SSIS package  as the Enumerator of a For Each container.

1. Create a For Each Loop Container.
2. Set the Enumerator to a "For Each ADO Enumerator".
3. Set the source variable to User::ObjShipment.
4. Assign each column from your object to its own variable in the Variable Mappings tab.
5. Within the For  Each Loop container, use those variables to do whatever you want: insert them into a database, do lookups and audits, etc.

If you are going to use a Script Task, then you all need to do is

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter oleDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleDa.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::objShipment"].Value);
```

And then use dt like any old DataTable.

Comment: Thanks!  This has helped me!

Comment: How do I also loop through a column of the record set ?

Comment: @blasto That's a bit vague, can you elaborate? Preferably with a question pointing to this one?

Comment: @KyleHale - I have a "result set". I want to pick a column from that. Then, I want to loop over the rows of that column using a FOR loop and NOT for each loop. How do I do that ?

Comment: Why won't a For Each loop satisfy you need in this situation?

Comment: @KyleHale - can you help me with an SSIS question over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936613/understanding-the-full-result-set-of-ssis Thanks.