# How to do a simple C# import?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Okay, this may seem silly. But, I don't know how to do an "import" in C#, in visual studio 2008. I know java, but not C#. Currently, I don't have the time to read a c# book. So, I need some help to get it right.

I was trying to use the code here - [SSIS Getting Execute Sql Task result set object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218451/ssis-getting-execute-sql-task-result-set-object)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter oleDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleDa.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::objShipment"].Value);
```

And I get the error - The type or namespace name 'OledDbDataAdapter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to do a java style import. But it failed.

```
using System.Data.OleDb::OleDbDataAdapter
```

Full code given below -

---

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ST_LongCodeGoesHere.csproj
{

    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        //To see the comment here, look at beyond end of this code.

        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            OledDbDataAdapter oleDbA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

**The comment was -**

```
   /*
            The execution engine calls this method when the task executes.
            To access the object model, use the Dts property. Connections, variables, events,
            and logging features are available as members of the Dts property as shown in the following examples.
        To reference a variable, call Dts.Variables["MyCaseSensitiveVariableName"].Value;
        To post a log entry, call Dts.Log("This is my log text", 999, null);
        To fire an event, call Dts.Events.FireInformation(99, "test", "hit the help message", "", 0, true);

        To use the connections collection use something like the following:
        ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
        cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";

        Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.

        To open Help, press F1.
    */
```

Comment: Don't add "::OleDbDataAdapter"

Comment: What's wrong with learning a little, tiny, amount of C# before trying to use it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - in 2-3 days for sure. Right now, just the bare minimum to to a small task.

Comment: @blasto: If you haven't got the time to learn even the basics of a language, you shouldn't try to use it IMO. You're trying to perform database access, which isn't trivial - just wait the 2-3 days before you start on it. Or start learning now, and then you'll be ready to do it sooner. Otherwise you're just going to be asking loads of questions which are trivial to anyone who's taken *any* time to learn C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet - valid points. but i am using this for SSIS and that too a small task. Once I am under less fire, I can breathe and really learn something before I jump in like this.

Comment: @JonSkeet - can you help me to figure this out, only this time ? I hear you have magical powers :)

Comment: @blasto: "It's important not to feed the pigeons if you don't want a lot of crap." - _Anon_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, you don't import individual types, you import whole namespaces. Something like this 
should work:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

...

OleDbDataAdapter oleDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();
```

Or you could create a type alias like this:

```
using OleDbDataAdapter = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter;
```

**Further Reading**

- [using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Comment: You can also use aliases for types by doing `using Alias = Qualified.Type.Name`

Comment: @blasto Have you added a reference to System.Data in your project?

Comment: Probably not so, Solution Explorer -> References -> Add reference -> Framework tab - > System.Data

Comment: @p.s.w.g - its already there. Should i put "using System.Data.OleDb;" just after all the "using statements". I am not sure if I am putting it in the right place.

Comment: @blasto It needs to be in the same place as the other using directives, but they don't need to be in any particular order.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - yes, but in my line of code, I get an error on LHS and no error on RHS ! OledDbDataAdapter oleDbA = new OleDbDataAdapter(); LHS = Left hand side of = sign.

Comment: @Tafari - does not work. I added System.data version2.0 of .NET.

Comment: @blasto If you've got the reference in your project and the using directive in your file, it should work. Can you post a bit more of your code?

Comment: @p.s.w.g - sure. give me a few seconds

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Okay, i added it. can you help me to figure it out ?

Comment: @blasto The problem is `OledDbDataAdapter` is misspelled. It should be `OleDbDataAdapter`. (no `d` between `Ole` and `Db`)

Comment: @p.s.w.g - omg ! I should take a break now. Thanks for helping me and pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer under your Solution find 'References' and add System.Data by right-clicking and 'Add reference'. You probably also want to type your import as: using System.Data.OleDb;

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx

- You need to add the reference, before you can use it.